# How to get tomorrow date time i.e end of the day in miliseconds

Tags: java, android, datetime, timestamp

i need to know tomorrows end date time in milliseconds. to get current datetime in miliseconds we use

```
long dateTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis(); // 12/6/2014 7.50 PM
```

if today date is 12/6/2014 7:50 PM and Tomorrow date is 13/6/2014 and it ends on 11:59 PM. i need this in milliseconds.

Comment: So you want the last millisecond of the next day? E.g. `11:59:59.999`?

Comment: Incidentally, a nice fat down-vote from me. It doesn't appear you've tried anything at all, which is disappointing for a 2.5k user. All you've done is specify your requirements.

Comment: @Duncan, you are right...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following is how you get the end of tomorrow -

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); //current date and time      
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); //add a day
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23); //set hour to last hour
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59); //set minutes to last minute
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59); //set seconds to last second
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999); //set milliseconds to last millisecond
long millis = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

Comment: I must agree that using `Calendar.getInstance()` might be more advantageous then `new GregorianCalendar();`

Comment: If we dont add a day, will it show the end time for today in Millis.?

Answer (score 3):

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long endOfTomorrow = currentTime + DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS
            + (DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS - currentTime % DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS);
```

Comment: I like this solution most, but it does not take timezone into account.

To make it work with timezone, I had to subtract also this value:

`
int gmtOffset = TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset();
`

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.setTime(dateTimestamp);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

calendar.getTime(); // retrieves msec time of the time set in calendar
```